# click and on click fires only on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` and it is only firing on the second click, it seems that is has something to do with the code inside because when I remove all the stuff and make an alert it fires on the first click. But I could not figure out what is wrong.

I tried so switch `.on('click'...)` or `.click(...)` and `preventDefault()` but it does not make the change.

If it does matter, it is a Chrome extension

```js
data = ["test", "test2", "test3"];
let ids = [];
let visitedCount = 0;
let visitSpeed = 1000;
let visited = [];
let db = null;
const mVisitDB = new Map();

//injected html
injectedhtml = `
    <div id="container--start-counter">
        <span id="counter--status">
            Start
        </span>
        <span id="counter--count"></span>
    </div>`;

data = []; // this array gets filled with usernames live
let visitedCount = 0;
let visitSpeed = 1000;
let visited = [];

$("#counter--status").on("click", function (e) {
  if ($(this).text() === "Start") {
    $(this).text("Stop");

    $(data).each(function (index, username) {
      let eUsername = username;
      setTimeout(function () {
        if ($("#counter--status").text() == "Stop") {
          $("#container--profiles--visited").html(visitedCount);
          var percentRound = (
            (visitedCount / data.length) *
            100 *
            1.025
          ).toFixed(0);
          $("#container--bottom--status").html(
            "Remaining: " + percentRound + "% - Visiting: " + eUsername
          );

          if (jQuery.inArray(eUsername, visited) == -1) {
            visited.push(eUsername);
            visitedCount += 1;
            fetch("https://www.theurls.com", {
              headers: {
                "x-api-key": "XXX",
                "x-session-id": "XXX",
              },
            })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((data) =>
                // addUser is adding stuff to indexedDB
                addUser(eUsername)
              );
          }
        }
      }, visitSpeed * index);
    });
  } else {
    $("#counter--status").text("Start");
    $("#counter--count").html("");
  }
});

function addUser(username) {
  const user = {
    user: username,
    cTime: Date.now(),
  };

  const tx = db.transaction("username", "readwrite");
  const addUser = tx.objectStore("username");
  addUser.add(user);
}

function addBlockedUser(username) {
  const user = {
    user: username,
    cTime: Date.now(),
  };

  const tx = db.transaction("blocked_user", "readwrite");
  const addUser = tx.objectStore("blocked_user");
  addUser.add(user);
}

function viewUser() {
  const tx = db.transaction("username", "readonly");
  const cuser = tx.objectStore("username");
  const request = cuser.openCursor();

  request.onsuccess = (e) => {
    const cursor = e.target.result;

    if (cursor) {
      mVisitDB.set(`${cursor.key}`, `${cursor.value.cTime}`);

      cursor.continue();
    }
  };
}

createDB();
```

Comment: The code shown is full of syntax errors and won't run at all.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The initial text content of your element is _not_ `=== "Start"` - there is whitespace before and after that. It works on the second click, because on the first click, you explicitly set `.text("Start")` in the else branch.

Comment: @CBroe wow, how stupid can I be. Thank you very much for that.